# What are your favorite little used C# trick?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Hidden Features of C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c)

Hello Everyone,

I'm just wondering what little C# tricks that programmers use in their day-to-day work.

I have two - One, an overlooked, for me, language feature.  The other a solution to an often occuring need.

## 1 - Returning a default value (often from collections like ViewState or Session)

How often do you write code like this?

```
if(Session["VariableName"] != null && ....
```

or

```
if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["VariableName"]) ...
```

To retrieve the value.

Well, Resharper slapped me on the hand the first time I tried that after I had installed it.  It said to use this instead:

```
var MyVariable = Session["VariableName"] ?? string.empty
```

Soooo much easier.

## 2 - Counting the number of sub-strings in a string (Without looping in my code).

```
string myString = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, " +   
"consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod " + 
"tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna " + 
"aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud " +
"exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip " +    
"ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure " + 
"dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit " +    
"esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. " +    
"Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, " +    
"sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim " +    
"id est laborum.";

string mySubString = "dolor";
int Count = (myString.Length - myString.Replace(mySubString, string.Empty).Length) / mySubString.Length;
```

Comment: <3 ternary operator. It's one of the most useful shortcuts, in any language.

Comment: "trick" 1 - does not work when your code needs to know that the value is actually missing.

Comment: #1 would be nice if you're sure your object returned null instead of throwing `System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException`.

Comment: "trick" 2 - it sounds cool, but is actually a bit more expensive than just looping and using `String.IndexOf(String, Int32)`